# Import of data into Neo4j with Python takes time

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Anyone experienced parsing and importing data into Neo4j using `py2neo` and Python? I'm currently trying to parse an relatively large (18700r x 17c) .csv file and store its created nodes and relations into Neo. By using py2neo, one must first create a model inheriting from py2neo.data.Node and then use

```
for n in nodes:
    tx = graph.begin()
    tx.create(node)

for r in relations:
    tx = graph.begin()
    tx.create(r)
```

to store all data. To parse the data and store it takes roughly about 2.5 min (real time) when running with `time python ...`, where its about half-half of time taking for parse and store.

Another way is to create a big query string, which I manage to do. When this is done one can run `graph.run(big_query_string)` to do the same job. Now it takes about 3 seconds to parse and 2.5 min to store. When I run the same query string directly in the browser it took over 3 minutes.

We are 2 people on the same project. Me on Neo4j and another on DGraph. It's in its core the same parsing code, but to store on DGraph takes at most 5 seconds...

Anyone having experiences on this?

**UPDATE**
There are exactly 115139 "CREATE" statements in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Py2neo is not optimised for large imports such as this. You are better off using one of the dedicated import tools for Neo4j instead.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Seams like only reasonable importing tools they have are for .csv-files. So what I did was to parse the data from a single csv-file into two nodes and relations.csv. Now, it is all done in less than 10s for a dataset of 1823 node,   122600 relationships and 3645 properties. Im happy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is iterating node by node. If you have lots of data to import, using a CSV file will be much more efficient. Maybe your current CSVs can be used directly?

I use python code to create, modify or directly use CSV files and then import them. I am not a python guru, but this will give you a example of one way to do this:

First, setting up the connection to Neo4j

```
import Neo4jLib
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
from py2neo import Graph, Path, Node, Relationship  #http://py2neo.org/v3/
import re

importDir="C:\\Users\\david\\.Neo4jDesktop\\neo4jDatabases\\database-49f9269f-5936-4b08-96b7-c2b3fa3006fa\\installation-3.3.5\\import\\"

def Neo4jConnectionSetup( ):
    uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "your password"))
```

Upload:

```
def UploadWithPeriodicCommit(Q):
    try:
        uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "your password"))
        with driver.session() as session:
            session.run(Q)
```

where q is the cyper query, such as:

```
Neo4jLib.UploadWithPeriodicCommit("USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///vcf.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
merge (p:PosNode{Pos:toInteger(line.Pos)})")
```

Your CSV should go in the Import directory of the database in use. You specify only its name and not the full path.

These uploads and updates run fast.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This would probably work as well. As I mentioned in a comment on last reply, my solution was to export it to two new .csv files with nodes in one, relationships in the other and use ```./bin/neo4j-admin import --nodes=nodes.csv --relationships=relations.csv``` to import it into Neo.